# Validating Excel values via a unique ID, while also fetching the date and name of a record

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet that I'm making, which I'm trying to format so if you enter a value, it looks up the ID, then pulls the relevant date and name of the record via Excel. But, I don't know exactly how to do this.

Can someone help?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZqkZ.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify where/how you input the ID you want to search for, so in my example I am assuming `G4` as the cell to evaulate.

```
=INDEX($B$6:$B$9; MATCH($G$4; $D$6:$D$9; 0))
```

Place this formula in G3. When you input a valid ID in G4, G3 will now fetch the corresponding value from column B. So if you input `BBB` in G4, G3 would show `John`.

[image: INDEX/MATCH]

Here's a screenshot. The formula looks weird because it's localized to Norwegian language - but I promise that it's an index/match formula.

We can get fancier as well - if there is no valid ID in the selected range, the formula will evaluate to #I/T or #VALUE or some other unhelpful error. What's better is to define it ourselves:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$6:$B$9; MATCH($G$4; $D$6:$D$9; 0)); "ID not found!")
```

Comment: When I input the first code into the excel sheet, it keeps throwing errors, before and after I've reformatted it to apply it to my own spreadsheet. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Depending on your calculation settings, the formula may not have updated yet. Try going into edit-mode in the cell the formula is contained in, then press `Enter` without changing anything. This will force an update.

Comment: It won't allow me to enter the code at all without "fixing" it. the problem seems to be around the "MATCH" area. it simply says the formula is incorrect, and demands you fix it before leaving the cell.

Comment: Is your version of Excel language-localized? If so, you can't use the english formula names.

Comment: I think so? This version seems to be pulling from the english-UK dictionary, so I think it can use those formula names.

Comment: Ok, maybe the formula is wrong for some reason after you altered it. What is the range you want to match values against (in the screepcap I posted, this will be column D, from row 6 to 9), and what does your formula now look like?

Comment: The sheet has since changed, but the column would now be column i, rows 7-10000. the value to check is in D2. then I need to somehow use that to fetch the values for the name(B7-10000) and redeemed(H7-10000) columns

Comment: Name: `=INDEX($B$7:$B$10000; MATCH($D$2; $I$7:$I$10000; 0))`  
Redeemed: `=INDEX($H$7:$H$10000; MATCH($D$2; $I$7:$I$10000; 0))`

Comment: The syntax explanation is this: Index - this is what column to fetch from. Match determines which row to fetch from, after searching for the first argument in the range given by 2nd argument. 3rd argument is how to match (exact, close, etc). I can add a screencap that shows this relationship to my answer if you need a visualization.

Comment: No, I'm still having issues. I've just put in "Redeemed"'s code, and it's come up with this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3922896/ExcelError.png

From there on, trying to click off of it simply messes up the formula, and it does not calculate x_x

Comment: How very odd... any chance you can upload the workbook in example form? Perhaps the one imaged there, but without any data that I presume is personal to someone?

Comment: Sure thing! here is the spreadsheet, sans-important info! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3922896/Spreadsheet2.xlsx

Comment: AH, that did it! thanks a bunch, Vsoraas and Pnuts! ^^

Comment: So it was a localization "issue" after all... :-) happy to help.